# Is there any function to add Workbook in EPPLUS?

Tags: c#, .net, epplus

How to write this Code in EPPLUS?

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook Workbook = Excel.Workbooks.Add(System.Type.Missing);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Unfortunately, your question, as it stands, is unclear: A new workbook in Excel is just a new file. Are you asking how to create a new Excel file in EPPlus?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=epplus+create+workbook (e.g. code sample under https://riptutorial.com/epplus)

Comment: Thanks a lot for Links! But I want to rewrite this Code via EPPLUS function or properties.                                              Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook Workbook = Excel.Workbooks.Add(System.Type.Missing);

Comment: @jimitimi: Then the answer is: It's not possible, since no EPPlus method returns a value of type `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook`. What I want to say by that is: You won't be able to convert your code line-by-line! You need to understand what a block of code *does* and *then* you can try to reimplement it with EPPlus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a boilerplate for creating a new spreadsheet in EPPlus:

```
FileInfo newFile = new FileInfo(fileName);
ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(newFile);
ExcelWorksheet ws = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");

// Do some stuff
ws.Cells["A1"].Formula = "=TODAY()";
ws.Cells[2, 1].Value = "Hello World";

package.Save();
```

You could do it with the empty constructor (no file info specified), but you'll eventually have to declare that, so I always find it useful to do it up front.

Comment: I have a wrote code,and i must change it via epplus. and I don't know, which code should i replace instead this :                                                                 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook Workbook = Excel.Workbooks.Add(System.Type.Missing);

Comment: @jimitimi: IMHO that's exactly what the answer is about